# Any resources for iPhone/Android App development in PHP

Tags: php, android, iphone, mobile-application

So I just finished developing a website built completely in PHP using the Instagram API... I want to create an app for iPhones and Android.

My question: Is there an easy way to develop apps in PHP for the iPhone or Android devices? I know they're developed using Java, but I don't know Java all that well... I would much prefer PHP, does anyone have experience with this?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: I've come across ipfaces.org, any insight?

Comment: Please reword your question to be actually answerable in a constructive way. "does anyone have experience with" is a good way to get a question closed as NC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that the best way is to use webView:

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/

Answer (score 1):

i don't think it is possible to develop an application using PHP for iOS/Android App development, but you can make use of HTML5, CSS3, Javascript. there are few cross browser mobile application development platform available, below are the link to few of them.

http://www.appcelerator.com/

http://www.phonegap.com/

http://www.coronalabs.com/

http://www.kendoui.com/

Comment: Its possible now. :)
http://venturebeat.com/2012/10/23/huge-news-php-developers-can-now-design-build-and-publish-mobile-apps-right-in-zend-studio/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the android SL4A library for php development in android.
 http://phpforandroid.net/doku.php?do=export_odt&id=start